# PowerBIClient generates System.ArrayTypeMismatchException under certain circumstances

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have some really strange issue going on. With all the latest PowerBI nuget-packages and their latest iterations of dependencies I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArrayTypeMismatchException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
```

The stack trace shows me this:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V1.PowerBIClient.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V1.PowerBIClient..ctor(ServiceClientCredentials credentials, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Apps.Kinetic.Reports.Endpoint.Service.Reports.g1u0.GenerateAccessToken(String _Reference) in D:\*masked*.cs:line 575
```

While trying to look into the PowerBIClient source code I found on Initialize that it does attempt to add a class of type Iso8601TimeSpanConverter to a JsonConvert list, just have a look here:

```
/// </summary>
private void Initialize()
{
    this.Datasets = new Datasets(this);
    this.Gateways = new Gateways(this);
    this.Imports = new Imports(this);
    this.Workspaces = new Workspaces(this);
    this.Reports = new Reports(this);
    this.BaseUri = new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com");
    SerializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        ContractResolver = new ReadOnlyJsonContractResolver(),
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                new Iso8601TimeSpanConverter()
            }
    };
    DeserializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        ContractResolver = new ReadOnlyJsonContractResolver(),
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                new Iso8601TimeSpanConverter()
            }
    };
    CustomInitialize();
}
```

I can't figure out why this is occurring in my application while in the demo sample with a few versions behind, has it fully working. But I do know that I also had it working when I at first used a regular .NET console app in 4.6.1. But now I'm using a .NET Core console app using the .NET 4.6.1 framework. Everything but this works just fine.

Here's the screenshot of the problem:

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrPfw.png)

I found this developer with a similar issue a while back but not related to PowerBI. No answer however.

[Adding Iso8601TimeSpanConverter to JsonConverter list throws ArrayTypeMismatch exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339605/adding-iso8601timespanconverter-to-jsonconverter-list-throws-arraytypemismatch-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the issue you provided now contains a hint that helped me to resolve this problem. In my case it was caused by multiple versions of Newtonsoft.Json.dll installed in GAC. After I configured my app to resolve the library reference to a latest version, the exception is gone.